# External USB Audio not being picked up by Macbook Pro

Tags: audio, usb

I've just bought the brand new 13" Retina Macbook pro. I'd like to hook it up to my USB DAC (An Audio Engine D1) When I plug in the USB to the Macbook it doesn't pick up anything. I've restarted the laptop to no effect. Nothing is being displayed in the Output section of Sound in System Preferences.

The DAC is supposed to be plug and play and has been working fine on my Windows machine for years.

How can I set up external audio on a Macbook Pro?

Comment: Try booting with it attached.

Comment: @Tetsujin This does not work either.

Comment: If you have another, or can get access to another, it would be great if you could try that out as well. If it doesn't work, it is most likely a driver related issue.

Comment: In @Garex question, you mention it doesn't show up in any app, meaning it is not recognized by the computer. This can mean that it is faulty (which it most likely is not), or Apple doesn't have a good (or any) driver for it.

Comment: Could it be a driver issue? From http://audioengineusa.com/Store/D1-24-Bit-DAC, FAQs tab: "(...) the drivers [the D1] uses are developed and provided by (...) your computer's OS. In the case of a Windows PC (...), these drivers are provided by Microsoft, and are a part of Windows." Have you tried this (same link)? "Try a NVRAM/PRAM reset. This resets the system configurations for some audio and video related settings and can many times help clear up problems related to audio. See the link below from Apple’s support page for information on how to do this. http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379"

Comment: Are you connection the Audioengine D1 directly to the Macbook Pro, or is it roughing through a USB HUB? I’m also assuming that you have tried a different USB cable just to make sure it’s not that.

Comment: @kenjikato Yes, directly into USB with no hub. I have tried both USB ports. Both work correctly with other USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be helpful to know the exact model and the brand.

Second, could you please give this a try:

- Plug your DAC in,
- open the Audio-MIDI-Setup utiilty from the Utilities folder and
- check whether it appears?

If not, try to create a device for it... Just a crazy idea...

Comment: The USB DAC is an Audioengine D1 http://audioengineusa.com/Store/D1-24-Bit-DAC

When I plug in the DAC, all I see in the Audio-MIDI-Setup screen is Built-in Microphone and Built-in Output.

I'm not sure how to create a device, this is the first time I'm using OSX and a Mac, I'll look it up and try.

Comment: To just add one, click on the Plus sign on the left bottom of the device overview....

Comment: Is it in the list here?
Open Terminal.app and enter:

ioreg -p IOUSB

Comment: No, it isn't there either.

Comment: Last ideas I have before I have to admit I cannot help you: :-)

- Try another USB port.
- Plug it in before booting.
- reset parameter RAM and SMC and reboot.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help either. I've seen many people )who I think have older macbooks) use this DAC.